# How to recover data from a DiscreteWaveletTransform with Battle-Lemarie Wavelets?

Tags: wavelet-analysis

The question is why can data be recovered perfectly from a discrete wavelet transform with a Haar wavelet but not with some Battle-Lemarie wavelets?

A simple example with the `HaarWavelet[]`:

```
data3 = Table[Random[Real, 10], {k, 30}]

{0.702135, 4.9963, 4.89421, 9.69088, 0.396075, 0.781406, 
6.41113, 6.82329, 6.51081, 7.93571, 9.42005, 9.27458, 4.27116, 
2.14756, 6.01304, 7.76658, 7.86689, 9.94061, 7.02273, 6.3883, 
7.34664, 4.71568, 4.7454, 5.27213, 6.64451, 9.71938, 9.85119, 
5.58125, 6.24843, 8.93798}

re2 = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data3, HaarWavelet[], WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

InverseWaveletTransform[re2]
{0.702135, 4.9963, 4.89421, 9.69088, 0.396075, 0.781406, 6.41113, 
6.82329, 6.51081, 7.93571, 9.42005, 9.27458, 4.27116, 2.14756, 
6.01304, 7.76658, 7.86689, 9.94061, 7.02273, 6.3883, 7.34664, 
4.71568, 4.7454, 5.27213, 6.64451, 9.71938, 9.85119, 5.58125, 
6.24843, 8.93798}
```

And now the same with a Battle-Lemarie wavelet:

```
data3 = Table[Random[Real, 10], {k, 30}]

{4.57767, 9.00061, 4.69697, 2.98705, 0.880157, 9.86854, 
4.00198, 4.89448, 3.5703, 5.21159, 0.666989, 2.34296, 9.20806, 
6.2718, 4.95437, 4.33022, 3.7734, 3.56578, 1.39766, 2.00157, 9.25936, 
5.37673, 2.39729, 6.44292, 4.68169, 6.37612, 7.70032, 3.45587, 
3.80153, 6.50759}

re2 = 
 DiscreteWaveletTransform[data3, BattleLemarieWavelet[1, 10], 
  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

InverseWaveletTransform[re2]

{4.22627, 11.0403, 4.47468, 1.00538, 2.57364, 12.6589, 
2.97526, 2.00396, 0.903247, 4.00951, 1.49102, 0.706097, 7.48314, 
8.84186, 6.57139, 2.88699, 1.16318, 2.09853, 2.98261, 1.89232, 
7.64724, 7.39258, 5.25025, 6.75834, 5.33315, 8.11338, 7.85654, 
3.73812, 5.31351, 6.48029}
```

I know I can increase the precision by taking a higher value then 10 within the calculation of the Battle-Lemarie wavelet, but since I'm limited in this case by 30 data points, I can't get a perfect reconstruction?

Thanks for some help :).

Answer (score 2):

When taking transforms and their inverses, it is necessary to use the same options in both operations. In your case, you need to tell the `InverseWaveletTransform` to use the `BattleLemarieWavelet` option since you gave this option to the `DiscreteWaveletTransform`, that is:

```
InverseWaveletTransform[re2, BattleLemarieWavelet[1, 10]]
```

will recover the input data.

Comment: I tried that before and this will **not** recover the data. You tried that with your mathematica? I'm using mathematica 8 what's your version you tested it with?

Comment: It works fine. It does give back the same data you start with. I'm using ver. 10.

Comment: So than it seems so be a bug in Mathematica 8. It's possible since the wavelet analysis was added first time in version 8. Thank you :).